# array data including html tags to json string

Tags: php, json

How can I get `json` string from this array:

```
$test['author'] = '<p>Written By: <a href="">Someone</a></p>';

echo json_encode($test); // removed erroneous question mark
```

[in real, this string came from `sql select query`.]

Any ideas?

Comment: What part of what you've done doesn't work? Yes, you can pass an array to `json_encode` and it'll work fine.

Comment: If you're viewing that directly in a browser, most likely the html's being rendered. View the page source and you'll see the raw json string.

Comment: What do you mean by `json string from array`?

Comment: Marc B you're right, I tried to view json output in a browser and then copy&paste it into a json formatter and got error msg:"JSON is not well formated", now I take raw json string from page source, it works fine :)

Answer (score 6):

Based on Marc B's comment what will probably fix this for you is:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($test));
```

That way your `<p>` tags (and any others) will be changed to `&lt;p&gt;` and such won't be interpreted by your browser as HTML.